# Android opengl screenshot with alpha channel support

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es, bitmap, screenshot

I'm currently developing an augmented reality application in android. Textured openGL object is drawn over the camera view. I had tried so many methods to take the screen shot of android openGL view (GLSurfaceview). But no success. I want the screenshot with transparent background so that I could draw it over camera image to produce an ARImage. Can any one help me? I know that I have to read the pixels of opengl using glReadPixels() function. I tried it using GL_RGBA mode and created bitmap (used ARGB_8888 and RGB_565). Using ARGB_8888 format I'll get a transparent image with no object and in RGB_565 mode I'll get a image filled with black color. Can any one guide me? Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Midhun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I found the solution to my question and I'll paste the code here. It may be useful for others who need alpha support.

```
public static Bitmap SavePixels(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
{  
     int b[]=new int[w*(y+h)];
     int bt[]=new int[w*h];
     IntBuffer ib=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
     ib.position(0);
     gl.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y+h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

     for(int i=0, k=0; i<h; i++, k++)
     {//remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
      //and so, some correction need.        
          for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
          {
               int pix=b[i*w+j];
               int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
               int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
               int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
               bt[(h-k-1)*w+j]=pix1;
          }
     }


     Bitmap sb=Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     return sb;
}
```

Comment: i'm getting erroneal colours with this solution, for example, yellow colours are painted as blue colours...¿? how to solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

This so called "solution" is simply making a screen shot. Alpha values that you get from glReadPixels are up to full 255 although you didn't draw anything to those pixels. If it's possible it will be an OpenGL-settings solution.